# Fastest way to check if a string contains specific characters in any of the items in a list

Tags: python, performance, list, iteration

What is the fastest way to check if a string contains some characters from any items of a list?

Currently, I'm using this method:

```
lestring = "Text123"

lelist = ["Text", "foo", "bar"]

for x in lelist:
    if lestring.count(x):
        print 'Yep. "%s" contains characters from "%s" item.' % (lestring, x)
```

Is there any way to do it without iteration (which will make it faster I suppose.)?

Comment: I don't think you can do it without iteration. `if x in lestring` works as well though, and probably faster since it doesn't need to count how many times it appears.

Comment: Pretty much any time you're doing string comparison or substring searches, you're going to have at least one level of iteration. By the way, the `count()` method is almost certainly implemented iteratively, so we're looking at at least O(mn), which is probably near optimal for this problem. Also, strictly speaking, your solution searches for substrings (which may be what your meant), but won't say `lestring` contains at least one of 'T', 'e', 'x', or 't'. Did I misread you, or is this latter case what you actually want?

Comment: Do you need to know if more than one of the strings in the list can be found in the test string? Also, in the actual application, do you expect to have a great many strings in the list, to have many strings to test, and roughly how long do you expect those strings to be? I have a Python script that essentially does what you're asking for in a fairly naive fashion for dozens of MS-Word and PDF files and it takes only seconds to do the job, so I haven't found the need to optimise it further.

Comment: Building a regex that includes the listed strings would be an option, but only timing the different implementation options with realistic test data would tell you which option was fastest.

Comment: @Volatility: Hmm good point
@jpm: Nope, if `lestring` contains the `x` fully.

Comment: @Simon I only need the boolean value actually, if the string is contained in any of the list items.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try list comprehension with membership check

```
>>> lestring = "Text123"
>>> lelist = ["Text", "foo", "bar"]
>>> [e for e in lelist if e in lestring]
['Text']
```

Compared to your implementation, though LC has an implicit loop but its faster as there is no explicit function call as in your case with `count`

Compared to Joe's implementation, yours is way faster, as the filter function would require to call two functions in a loop, `lambda` and `count`

```
>>> def joe(lelist, lestring):
    return ''.join(random.sample(x + 'b'*len(x), len(x)))

>>> def uz(lelist, lestring):
    for x in lelist:
        if lestring.count(x):
            return 'Yep. "%s" contains characters from "%s" item.' % (lestring, x)


>>> def ab(lelist, lestring):
    return [e for e in lelist if e in lestring]

>>> t_ab = timeit.Timer("ab(lelist, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import lelist, lestring, ab")
>>> t_uz = timeit.Timer("uz(lelist, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import lelist, lestring, uz")
>>> t_joe = timeit.Timer("joe(lelist, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import lelist, lestring, joe")
>>> t_ab.timeit(100000)
0.09391469893125759
>>> t_uz.timeit(100000)
0.1528471407273173
>>> t_joe.timeit(100000)
1.4272649857800843
```

---

Jamie's commented solution is slower for shorter string's. Here is the test result

```
>>> def jamie(lelist, lestring):
    return next(itertools.chain((e for e in lelist if e in lestring), (None,))) is not None

>>> t_jamie = timeit.Timer("jamie(lelist, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import lelist, lestring, jamie")
>>> t_jamie.timeit(100000)
0.22237164127909637
```

---

If you need Boolean values, for shorter strings, just modify the above LC expression

```
[e in lestring for e in lelist if e in lestring]
```

Or for longer strings, you can do the following

```
>>> next(e in lestring for e in lelist if e in lestring)
True
```

or

```
>>> any(e in lestring for e in lelist)
```

Comment: +1 I think you could turn it into a generator, `itertools.chain` it with a `None`, and fetch the first occurrence with `next`, to break early from the loop if there is a coincidence, should be faster: `if next(itertools.chain((e for e in lelist if e in lestring), (None,))) is not None : ...`

Comment: @Jaime:I could also use `any` (as OP only wants a boolean result), but for shorter strings, LC would be faster compared to generator even when employing short-circuit. There was a debate on this some months back on SO.

Comment: What if I only need a boolean value? Doesn't matter how many times the item appears in the string.

Comment: Thank you for running it through `timeit` to validate your claim; since the discussion is speed. I'm curious though, what do you consider a *longer string*?

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(lambda x: lestring.count(x), lelist)
```

That will return all the strings that you're trying to find as a list.

Comment: This is slower than OP's implementation.

Comment: Since the discussion is speed, you probably should run it through `timeit` to validate your claim.

Answer (score 1):

if the test is to see if there are any characters in common (not words or segments), create a set out of the letters in the list and then check the letters agains the string:

```
char_list = set(''.join(list_of_words))
test_set = set(string_to_teat)
common_chars = char_list.intersection(test_set)
```

However I'm assuming you're looking for as little as one character in common...

Comment: What if the hay or the needle has repeated characters?

Comment: you could do the same idea checking words by using split() on the input string and comparing sets of whole words. But this won't work for substrings

Comment: Since the discussion is speed, you probably should run it through `timeit` to validate your claim.

Answer (score 0):

The **esmre** library does the trick. In your case, the simpler, **esm** (part of esmre) is what you want.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esmre/

https://code.google.com/p/esmre/

They have good documentation and examples:
Taken from their examples:

```
>>> import esm
>>> index = esm.Index()
>>> index.enter("he")
>>> index.enter("she")
>>> index.enter("his")
>>> index.enter("hers")
>>> index.fix()
>>> index.query("this here is history")
[((1, 4), 'his'), ((5, 7), 'he'), ((13, 16), 'his')]
>>> index.query("Those are his sheep!")
[((10, 13), 'his'), ((14, 17), 'she'), ((15, 17), 'he')]
>>>
```

I ran some performance tests:

```
import random, timeit, string, esm

def uz(lelist, lestring):
    for x in lelist:
        if lestring.count(x):
            return 'Yep. "%s" contains characters from "%s" item.' % (lestring, x)



def ab(lelist, lestring):
    return [e for e in lelist if e in lestring]


def use_esm(index, lestring):
    return index.query(lestring)

for TEXT_LEN in [5, 50, 1000]:
    for SEARCH_LEN in [5, 20]:
        for N in [5, 50, 1000, 10000]:
            if TEXT_LEN < SEARCH_LEN:
                continue

            print 'TEXT_LEN:', TEXT_LEN, 'SEARCH_LEN:', SEARCH_LEN, 'N:', N

            lestring = ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(TEXT_LEN)))
            lelist = [''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(SEARCH_LEN))) for _
                      in range(N)]

            index = esm.Index()
            for i in lelist:
                index.enter(i)
            index.fix()

            t_ab = timeit.Timer("ab(lelist, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import lelist, lestring, ab")
            t_uz = timeit.Timer("uz(lelist, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import lelist, lestring, uz")
            t_esm = timeit.Timer("use_esm(index, lestring)", setup="from __main__ import index, lestring, use_esm")

            ab_time = t_ab.timeit(1000)
            uz_time = t_uz.timeit(1000)
            esm_time = t_esm.timeit(1000)

            min_time = min(ab_time, uz_time, esm_time)
            print '  ab%s: %f' % ('*' if ab_time == min_time else '', ab_time)
            print '  uz%s: %f' % ('*' if uz_time == min_time else '', uz_time)
            print '  esm%s %f:' % ('*' if esm_time == min_time else '', esm_time)
```

And got that results depends mostly on the number of items that one is looking for (in my case, 'N'):

```
TEXT_LEN: 1000 SEARCH_LEN: 20 N: 5
  ab*: 0.001733
  uz: 0.002512
  esm 0.126853:

TEXT_LEN: 1000 SEARCH_LEN: 20 N: 50
  ab*: 0.017564
  uz: 0.023701
  esm 0.079925:

TEXT_LEN: 1000 SEARCH_LEN: 20 N: 1000
  ab: 0.370371
  uz: 0.489523
  esm* 0.133783:

TEXT_LEN: 1000 SEARCH_LEN: 20 N: 10000
  ab: 3.678790
  uz: 4.883575
  esm* 0.259605:
```

Comment: Provide relevant code from links, dont just post them

Comment: Since the discussion is speed, you probably should run it through `timeit` to validate your claim.