# Python dictionary, constant complexity way to return all keys in dict contain certain string

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

I have a dictionary like: `mydict = {'A B C':0, 'A B E':1, 'E F':0}`

Then I have a search key `search_string = 'A B'`

where I would like to find all keys and values that the search_string is part of the `mydict.keys()`. So in this can 'A B C' and 'A B E' will satisfy.

Since mydict can be very large. Is there a constant time complexity to search this rather than:

```
result = [search_string in key for key, val in mydict.items()]
```

I am also open to restructure the dictionary if needed.

Comment: Is `A B` always in the beginning? You could sort the keys and break if needed.

Comment: Yes they are sorted. But that is still no constant right? If the search is 'Z' then I need to go through all the beginning. Also this is to find subset not an exact match, so I guess you will never know without going through all, maybe this can't be done this way after all.

Comment: Sounds like a potential XY problem. What is the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: You are looking for ``m`` out of ``n`` keys (``m <= n``), how do you expect there to be an O(1) (constant time) solution? Are there any restrictions, such as the ``search_string`` always being at the start/end of the keys? Are any ``search_string``s known ahead of time?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070965/fastest-way-to-check-whether-a-string-is-a-substring-in-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the search is always for prefixes of string then you can use a [prefix tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-matching-python-using-pytrie-module/) or Trie which is an existing Python module.

> Trie allows finding matches in O(M) time, where M is the maximum
>   string length
>   [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)
>   (i.e. depends upon max key length rather than number of keys).

**Code**

```
from pytrie import StringTrie 

def create_prefix(dict):
" Creates a prefix tree based upon a dictionary "
  # create empty trie 
  trie = StringTrie() 

  for k in dict:
    trie[k] = k

  return trie
```

**Test 1**

```
# Preprocess to create prefix tree
mydict = {'A B C':0, 'A B E':1, 'E F':0}
prefix_tree = create_prefix(mydict)

# Now you can use search tree multile times to speed individual searches
for search_string in ['A B', 'A B C', 'E', 'B']:
  results = prefix_tree.values(search_string) # # .values resturn list that has this as a prefix
  if results:
    print(f'Search String {search_string} found in keys {results}')
  else:
    print(f'Search String {search_string} not found')
```

**Output**

```
Search String A B found in keys ['A B C', 'A B E']
Search String A B C found in keys ['A B C']
Search String E found in keys ['E F']
Search String B not found
```

**Test 2** (added to answer question from OP)

```
mydict = {'A B C':0, 'A B C D':0, 'A B C D E':0}
prefix_tree = create_prefix(mydict)
# Now you can use search tree multile times to speed individual searches
for search_string in ['A B', 'A B C', 'A B C D', 'A B C D E', 'B C']:
  results = prefix_tree.values(search_string) # # .values resturn list that has this as a prefix
  if results:
    print(f'Search String {search_string} found in keys {results}')
  else:
    print(f'Search String {search_string} not found')
```

**Output**

```
Search String A B found in keys ['A B C', 'A B C D', 'A B C D E']
Search String A B C found in keys ['A B C', 'A B C D', 'A B C D E']
Search String A B C D found in keys ['A B C D', 'A B C D E']
Search String A B C D E found in keys ['A B C D E']
Search String B C not found
```

Comment: Will it work for this case: `mydict = {'A B C':0, 'A B C D':0, 'A B C D E':0}`?

Comment: @MiniMax-yes, you just need to preprocess by calling `prefix_tree = create_prefix(mydict)`.  Then you can perform multiple searches.  The assumption is search are just for prefixes of keys and you will be performing multiple searches on a particular dictionary.

Comment: @MiniMax--updated answer with Test 2 to show working on the additional dictionary you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You have two potential solutions here- the first doesn't have O(1) complexity, but it's probably the way you'll want to go:

We can try building a tree and doing the search that way- so essentially:

You could have mydict look like this:

```
test_dict = {
    'A': {
        'B': {
            'C': 0,
            'E': 1
        }
    },
    'E': {
        'F': 1
    }
}

def get_recursive_values(mydict):
    results = []
    for key in mydict:
        if isinstance(mydict[key], dict):
            results.extend(get_recursive_values(mydict[key]))
        else:
            results.append(mydict[key])
    return results


def search(mydict, search_text):
    components = search_text.split(' ')
    if components[0] in mydict:
        next_res = mydict[components[0]]
        if isinstance(next_res, dict):
            if len(components) == 1:
                return get_recursive_values(next_res)
            return search(next_res, " ".join(components[1:]))
        else:
            return [mydict[components[0]]]
    raise KeyError(components[0])
```

Probably could be written a little nicer, but that'll work for you- try calling `search(test_dict, 'A B')`

and you'll get both the results.

Another potential solution would be, if you don't care about insertion time, to have all the values for all the different keys- this may sound a bit ridiculous, but you'll get values in O(1) time but insertion time will be large- i.e.

```
   'A': [0, 1],
   'A B': [0, 1],
   'A B C': [0],
   'A B E': [1],
   'E': [1],
   'E F': [1]
}

def insert(mydict, key, value):
    for k in mydict:
        if k.startswith(key):
            mydict[k].append(value)
    mydict[key] = [value]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the second solution please? I don't mind insertion time. It will be good to prepare a search map first