# fastest way to find one of several substrings in string

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm doing a lot of file processing where I look for one of several substrings in each line. So I have code equivalent to this:

```
with open(file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for key in MY_SUBSTRINGS:
            if key in line:
                print(key, line)
```

MY_SUBSTRINGS is a list of 6-20 substrings. Substrings vary in length 10-30 chars and may contain spaces.

I'd really like to find a much faster way of doing this. Files have many 100k lines in them. Lines are typically 150 chars. User has to wait for 30s to a minute while file processes. The above is not the only thing taking time but it's taking quite a lot. I'm doing various other processes on a line-by-line basis so not appropraite to search the whole file as once.

I've tried the regex and ahocorasick answers from here but they both come out slower in my tests:

[Fastest way to check whether a string is a substring in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070965/fastest-way-to-check-whether-a-string-is-a-substring-in-a-list-of-strings)

Any suggestions for faster methods?

I'm not quite sure of the best way to share example datasets. A logcat off an Android phone would be an example. One that's at least 200k lines long.

Then search for 10 strings like:

(NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for

Trying to associate with

Request to deauthenticate

interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED

---

I tried regexes like this:

```
match_str = "|".join(MY_SUBSTRINGS)
regex = re.compile(match_str)

with open(file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        match = regex.search(line)
        if match:
            print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: A regex that matches all your strings at once (`str1|str2|str3|etc`) will be much more efficient than a nested loop. You say you've tried regexes, but you haven't shown us _how_ you're using regular expressions. Using them the right way is important. If you do a separate regex search for each string, that'll be slower. One big regex search for _every_ string at the same time should be faster.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Are you sure? I thought compiling regex could be quite costly...

Comment: @Selnay, yes, compilation costs time, but it's a one-time up-front cost. And O(n) with the number of dictionary words is a _lot_ of time spent with the existing solution. We can do a lot and still be cheaper than it.

Comment: @quite68, ...if you can provide public datasets that have the same behavior you're testing against (even if they're pretty rough -- say, `/usr/share/dict` as the wordlist and any random textual dataset you'd like as the string to search for those words in), that would let folks providing answers concretely measure those answers against your stated data, and thus be able to make firm assertions about how fast they are or aren't in comparison to each other. Otherwise, nobody knows how well their assumptions fit to your actual data.

Comment: @quite68, once again, the details matter. Whether it's true depends on the size of your wordlists, the actual code used (I've seen people do very stupid things like compile a separate regex per word), etc. Nobody but you has the exact sample data you're testing with, and nobody has seen the exact code you're using, so how can you expect us to get the same results you have?

Comment: I tried a regex and it took twice a long as the method I posted in the question.

Comment: @quite68, once again, **show us the exact regex code you tried that took twice as long**. If there's a bug in that code, let us show how to fix it instead of writing off the approach altogether.

Comment: @quite68, ...and repeating myself on a second matter as well, **specify enough about your test dataset that we can be sure that our attempts to reproduce your stated performance characteristics are realistic**. How many words in the wordlist to be matched? How many characters in the dataset to be searched, and how many matches within it? Providing exact copies of the datasets would be best to ensure we aren't getting wildly different numbers only because we're testing wildly different datasets.

Comment: [Edit] into the question please, putting code in comments doesn't generally go well.

Comment: That said, the obvious problem there is that you're running a separate search per line

Comment: Don't do that -- search the whole file at once. If you want whole lines as your matches, write your regex so it expands beyond just the matched component to find the entire line.

Comment: As I said, I'm doing other processing per line so I need to work on a line by line basis.

Comment: That is, `regex = re.compile(r'^.*(?:foo|bar|baz).*$', re.MULTILINE)`, and then `regex.findall(yourEntireFile)` -- untested, but should provide the general idea.

Comment: You can match the whole line even if you're only looking for a smaller part of it.

Comment: If you can operate on the byte level (raw data, no encoding), you could try `mmap` (memory mapped file) for some speed increase.

Comment: @VPfB, ...is that actually going to make a difference here? If `file.read()` is fast (so the delay happens after we've already made an in-memory copy of the data), I wouldn't expect `mmap` to buy anything.

Comment: @quite68, ...if there are constraints that impact the range of acceptable answers, make sure they're clearly described in the question itself. When you say you need to operate line-by-line, that doesn't tell me if you're looking for other patterns in your lines (so you need them all for that reason), or you're needing to track line numbers, or if you just need the entire content of the lines that _do_ match your regex (which is what my comments above presume). Details matter.

Comment: You may also find [`re2`](https://pypi.org/project/re2/#performance) worth looking at. To say it's faster than the built-in `re` module would be... quite the understatement. (See https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for some background on how back in the 1970s regexes used to be extremely high-performance, and then thanks to extra "features" added by Perl and adopted throughout the industry lost their way).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I remember correctly, `mmap` reduces the overhead of kernel to userspace data copying.

Comment: @VPfB, yes, it does... but that copying (from the block cache into application memory) happens during a `read()`, so if `file.read()` is fast enough, the thing mmap would make faster isn't slow in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think it is a different system call (`mmap` and `open` - on Linux kernel at least). Anyway, without timing tests it is difficult to say, how much it helps. You might be true that not much.

Comment: @VPfB Specifically for a file that's read-only, the biggest advantage of mmap is that the block cache can be directly mapped into application space so there's no reason to copy the memory from the block cache over into newly-allocated application-space memory, so you save the allocation -- and also because everything gets mapped a page at a time, you don't pay for extra context switches for smaller-than-a-page reads if the application isn't written to operate efficiently. But in the case I'm comparing against of `bigstring = file.read()`, you can't have the worst-case one-read-per-character...

Comment: @VPfB, ...and anyhow, once the `read()` is completed everything is _already in memory on matter what_, so there's no further overhead from _not_ having chosen to use `mmap()`. (There are other advantages to it, sure -- f/e, mmap'd data can be "swapped out" without needing to actually use any swap; one just discards the pages and reads them from the file again if they're ever required -- but that isn't going to have any impact on our OP here)

Comment: @VPfB, ...and then there are cases, particularly for writes, where incautious use of mmap() can make performance worse -- any one-byte change invalidates the whole page, after all, and code manipulating memory is often written assuming random-access writes are cheap.

Comment: @VPfB, ...and all that said, `mmap` doesn't replace `open()` -- the syscall takes a file descriptor as an argument, so you have to call the `open` syscall to get the FD to pass to `mmap`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I take back my comment to try `mmap`.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a regular expression to search through the file.

Make sure that you're not running each of the search terms in loops when you use regex.

If each of your expressions are in one regexp it would look something like this:

```
import re

line = 'fsjdk abc def abc jkl'
re.findall(r'(abc|def)', line)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

If you need to to run still faster consider running a process concurrently with threads.  This is a much broader topic but one method that might work is to first take a look at your problem and consider what the bottleneck might be.

If the issue is that your look is starved for disk throughput on the read what you can do is first run through the file and split it up into chunks and then map those chunks to worker threads that can process the data like a queue.

Definitely would need some more on your problem to understand exactly what kind of issue you're looking to solve.  And there's people here that definitely would love to dig into a challenge.

Comment: I agree that this is the right solution, but the OP claims they've already tried using regexes. I think we need to get them to expand the question to clarify exactly what they tried and under what circumstances they found regexes to be slower before this (or any other answer) can be considered provably correct.

Comment: (Also, "just use threads" isn't really all that actionable, unless we go into _how_ to use threads in a way that makes sense for the specific problem space; have each thread search a subset of the input file? How, then, to avoid getting blocked on the GIL? -- unless the Python `re` library operates with the GIL unlocked, but whether or not it does is research that needs doing unless you know offhand)

Comment: Very true.  I was considering that using threads in general is a much deeper topic.  I could suggest a method that would work.